# slideDown and Up sub <li> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a simple menu using jquery.

I want to slideDown the sub `<li>` elements of another `<li>` (containing a ul) on mouseover of the parent element and slide them up if the mouse goes out of them.

At the moment I use this code but it does not work it slidesUp the child elements if I leave the parent element.

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSubLi() {
        //alert("Hallo");
        if (!$('#first').children().is(':visible')) {
            $('#first').children().slideDown();
        }

    }

    function hideSubLi() {
        //alert("Hallo");
        if ($('#first').children().is(':visible')) {
            $('#first').children().slideUp();
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li id="first" onmouseover="showSubLi();" style="background-color: Yellow">FirstLI
            <ul style="background-color: Green" onmouseout="hideSubLi();">
                <li>LI 1</li>
                <li>LI 2</li>
                <li>LI 3</li>
                <li>LI 4</li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#first').children().hide();
    });
</script>
```

What's wrong whith this code?

Comment: I should add that if I use hide() and show it works!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that this will get you close to what you want:

```
$('ul > li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
}).children('ul').hide();
```

**<sup>http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/De54m/</sup>**

Instead of inline events, which should not be used under almost any circumstances, we can use jQuery's event handling capability with the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function as well as [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle) to do away with the multiple `is(':visible')` calls.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the line `$('#first').children()` refers to the `ul` element instead of the `li` elements. Instead, you could use `$('#first>ul>li')`, which refers to the `li` elements.

Your corrected code:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSubLi() {
        //alert("Hallo");
        if (!$('#first>ul>li').is(':visible')) {
            $('#first>ul>li').slideDown();
        }

    }

    function hideSubLi() {
        //alert("Hallo");
        if ($('#first>ul>li').is(':visible')) {
            $('#first>ul>li').slideUp();
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
<ul>
    <li id="first" onmouseover="showSubLi();" style="background-color: Yellow">FirstLI
            <ul style="background-color: Green" onmouseout="hideSubLi();">
                <li>LI 1</li>
                <li>LI 2</li>
                <li>LI 3</li>
                <li>LI 4</li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#first>ul>li').hide();
    });
</script>
```